# How to remove files in order with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I'm running a code where I compress files and then remove them, but I need that after compressing 1 file from this list it already removes and continues to compress the others and following this compact order 1 already removes, I can do this by putting several if's with the names of the files, but this way it won't be bad, because every time I have a different file I will have to change the code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa0pz.png)

Comment: The only practical option is to combine those into one function.   That is, the task becomes "compress and remove".

Comment: (1) Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link. (2) Decide for one Python version and remove the other tag.

Answer (score 0):

## COMPACTAR ARQUIVOS

def compactar():
print ('******* COMPACTANDO ARQUIVOS *******')
with ZipFile(f'{nome_pasta}.rar', 'w') as pasta_comp:
for arquivo in tqdm((lista_arquivos)):
time.sleep(0.1)
if arquivo in lista_arquivos:
pasta_comp.write(arquivo)
compactar()

## REMOVER ARQUIVOS

def remover_arquivos():
print ('******* REMOVENDO ARQUIVOS *******')
for arquivo_remover in tqdm((lista_arquivos)):
time.sleep(0.1)
if arquivo_remover in lista_arquivos:
os.remove(arquivo_remover)
remover_arquivos()

Comment: Today it is already that way "compress and remove", but it is compressing all the files and then deleting, I need it to compress file 1 of this list and delete, compress file 2 of the list and delete

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).